# How do I stay on the current search match?

Tags: visual-studio-code, edit

I have not been using vscode for more than a year. Today when I used it again I can't find out how to stay on the current match for a search. Very confusing:

1. Control-F
2. Enter word to search for
3. Hit ENTER until the wanted match is highlighted
4. Hit ESCAPE

So far everything seems ok. But. When I hit for example LEFT-ARROW (or any other keyboard key) the character position jumps back to where I was before I started 1).

What is going on? I can't remember it worked like this?

Comment: What visual studio version are you using?

Comment: Version: 1.63.2
On Windows 10

Comment: Hmm, weird, seems to be working fine on mine machine.... Could you record some kind of short demo?

Comment: @TDiblik Hm, thanks. I tested and disabled my usual suspect, the Vim extension. Disabling Vim and restarting the problem was gone. But... enabling Vim again and restarting the problem still is gone... ??? So it seems to be a bug somewhere. At the moment I have no idea of where. Anyway, thanks for your reply. That helped a lot.

Comment: Hah, lol, I have a VIM extension too, but I let the Control-F command to be handled by the extension, so I usually use the vim "/" or search window in the task bar. (just a recommendation)

Comment: @TDiblik Eh, yes. I use both versions, but the VIM extension did not behave like the VIPER extension in Emacs so I got confused all the time.